# X sections within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw this

[image]

And thought it would be cool if I can dynamically change the colors and width of the colors with JS. The problem is I can use divs, but prefer not to. I've already tried gradients, but it didn't seem to work as expected. Any ideas on how to go about this? Additionally I'm not asking you to code this for me, rather a step of help. When I use it the div way and say set it to 33%, only 33% of the gradient shows. Not the 33% that corresponds to the color.

```
 .a{
  background-image:
linear-gradient(
  to right, 
  #fffdc2,
  #009dff 15%,
  #000 15%,
  #000 85%,
  #fffdc2 85%
);
position: fixed;
z-index: 1031;
top: 0;
height: 4px;
transition:all 1s;
}
```

Comment: please post some code, which you've already tried and not worked as expected for you

Comment: Did you use the inspector on what you saw? That would have given you more than enough of the information you need.

Comment: Done. Here's a fiddle http://jsbin.com/socaqozu/1 @rsz

Comment: Yeah, but it isn't dynamic.... @Marty

Answer (score 0):

Gradient is definitely the way to go. Use percentage positions for the colour stops.

For example, try this function:

```
function generateCSSGradient(colours) {
    var l = colours.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) colours[i] = colours[i].join(" ");
    return "linear-gradient( to right, "+colours.join(", ")+")";
}

var cols = [
    ["red","0%"],
    ["red","40%"],
    ["yellow","40%"], // note same percentage - this gives a crisp change
    ["yellow","60%"],
    ["green","60%"],
    ["green","80%"],
    ["blue","80%"],
    ["blue","100%"]
];
yourElement.style.background = generateCSSGradient(cols);
```

You can adjust and vary the colours however you want - add more, move them, change them, anything goes!

Comment: @user3624247 [It is](http://jsfiddle.net/wLZnL/1/), you were just selecting the element incorrectly and it had no height.

Comment: Well here's the problem. Enter some stuff in the forms and see the bar [here](http://jsbin.com/mivaxoyo/1). Now go here and look at [this](http://colourity.github.io/). Instead of having it like the first part I want to get it so that say you fill in one input. One part turns red. Then blue for the next. Just like the picture supplied.

Comment: Additionally I've been able to work [this](http://jsbin.com/ludukuwi/4) up, but it uses div. I want to find a div free way.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have to tag you. @NiettheDarkAbsol